# Enterprise Territory Management: Using Apex/SOQL get all accounts in UserId's territories

Tags: territory-management

I am trying to find a solution to getting all accounts in a users territory or territories with soql. I am not finding much info about it anywhere with Enterprise Territory Management.

EDIT: What I am confused about after looking at the ERD is how to get accountids associated to the rules? From what I see is objects with assignment rules but not specific object holding the ids associated with the rules.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you looked at the **[ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_territory2.htm)** at all?

Comment: Hello Adrian. I looked at the ERD and I can see how to get users in a territory. But what im am confused about is I dont see any account ids in any of the objects on the ERD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to look at [`ObjectTerritory2Association`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_objectterritory2association.htm).

> Represents an association (by assignment) between a territory and an object record, such as an account. Available only if Enterprise Territory Management has been enabled for your Salesforce org.

For instance, if you have a specific `Territory2` record and you want to get all related `Account` records, it might look like:

```
Territory2 territory; // = some value
List<Account> relatedAccounts = [
    SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ObjectId FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
        WHERE Territory2Id = :territory.Id
    )
];
```

Comment: ObjectTerritory2Association... Right in front of my face.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DerrickE If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: Ahh okay.. I always wondered how to mark as the best answer. thank you

Comment: I used Adrian's code in the Execute Anonymous window and added the following to set the territory value.

    Territory2 territory = new Territory2();
    territory.Id = 'some value';

I got a value for a Territory2 object from the query:

    SELECT Id, ObjectId, Territory2Id, AssociationCause, SobjectType, IsDeleted 
    FROM ObjectTerritory2Association.

I also added a debug loop to see the result:

    for (Account acc : relatedAccounts) {
        system.debug(acc);        
    }//next